# What is the gradient of d^2f/dxdy on image

Tags: image-processing

On my knowledge, 1st gradient of the image pixel on `x` can be approximated by `df/dx = f(x-1, y) - f(x+1, y)`, and `df/dy = f(x, y-1) - f(x, y+1)`

Question is, how can I compute the 2st gradient of `d^2f/dxdy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go deeper (Leonardo Dicaprio pic):

```
G = df/dx = f(x+1, y) - f(x-1,y)

Result = d^2f/dxdy 
= dG/dy 
= (f(x+1, y+1) - f(x-1,y+1)) - (f(x+1, y-1) - f(x-1,y+1))
```

Answer (score 4):

2nd one is no longer a gradient, but the local curvature. Be aware that curvatures can (and often will be) depend on what direction you're going (think for example about a saddle). Hence taking the partial derivatives of a gradient will actually give you a n×n tensor, where n is the dimensionality of your image (3D image = voxels, and so on).